# Android: Couldn't read row 0, col 3 from CursorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it

Tags: android, android-cursor

I'm working on a new app  and I'm getting an error: Couldn't read row 0, col 3 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

I'm using an external database (assets folder) and trying to get the name column from Auditoria table, name column from Categoria table and pregunta column from Preguntas table. So, i made a join which works perfectly fine. I tested on DB Browser for SQLite.

Can someone help me?

```
public AuditoriaModel getCriterioById(int id) {
    AuditoriaModel auditoriaModel = null;
    openDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT Auditoria.Name AS Auditorias, Categorias.Name AS Categoria, Preguntas.Pregunta AS Pregunta FROM Auditoria INNER JOIN Categorias ON Categorias.IdAuditoria = Auditoria.Id INNER JOIN Preguntas ON Preguntas.IdCategoria = Categorias.Id WHERE Preguntas.Id = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    auditoriaModel = new AuditoriaModel (cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getInt(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5));
    //Obtendremos un solo resultado
    cursor.close();
    closeDatabase();

    return auditoriaModel;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're selecting three columns but trying to read six.

Either remove the extra `get...()` reads, or add the missing columns to your `SELECT`.

(Another problem: Check the result of `moveToFirst()` in case the query matches nothing.)